# Copy a Shiny DT row to users clipboard

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, datatables-1.10, dt

Is there a way to have the selected row(s) in a shiny datatable (DT) be available for the user to copy (Ctrl+C) to their clipboard.  Ideally it would also supply the data table's column names or headers.

### UPDATE

global.R

```
library(rclipboard)
library(shiny)
```

ui.R:

```
...
rclipboardSetup(),
...
uiOutput("copy"),
```

server.R:

```
output$copy = renderUI({
    s = input$orders_rows_selected
    rclipButton("copybtm","Copy",data()[s,],icon("clipboard"))
  })
```

Comment: maybe you can try to add a download button for selected DT table

Comment: I did that, however I want to be able to quickly select specific rows and only copy those

Comment: it would definitely increase the prob to get an answer if you show us what you did so far,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist  So I showed you... any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to get a button to copy the selected rows. And there are the column headers too.

```
datatable(
  iris, 
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
  options = 
    list(
      select = TRUE,
      dom = "Bfrtip",
      buttons = list(
        list(
          extend = "copy",
          text = 'Copy',
          exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))
        )
      )
    )
)
```

Comment: Is there the possibility to modify the clipboard data, e. g. remove the column header and/or pick the content of a specific column?

Comment: @DerDressing Should be possible to remove the column header. Please open a new question. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Is there a way without using the "Select" extension? Doesn't play well with server mode.